# Remove color scheme options from user's profile page in WordPress 6.0

Tags: php, wordpress, color-scheme, wordpress-admin

I've always used this code in a must-use plugin to remove the whole color schemes section:

```
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );
```

Unfortunately, with WordPress 6.0 this does not work anymore. I've found that Core's `add_action( 'admin_color_...` was [recently moved](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/commit/325d8bab0a6b949ed912e783d143cbf90c1e0a58) from `default-filters.php` file to the `admin-filters.php` file, but I am unsure why and **how** I'd have to update the above snippet to make it work again.

Comment: Maybe better researched over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a `remove_action()` call to be effective, it needs to be called after the action you want to remove has been added, and before the action runs.

WordPress adds the `admin_color_scheme_picker` action in [admin-filters.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/admin-filters.php#L43) and then runs the action in the [user-edit.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/user-edit.php#L303) admin page template.

To remove the `admin_color_scheme_picker` action right before it is called on the user profile page, you can run the `remove_action()` call using the `admin_head-profile.php` hook:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php', 'wpse_72463738_remove_admin_color_scheme_picker' );

/**
 * Remove the color picker from the user profile admin page.
 */
wpse_72463738_remove_admin_color_scheme_picker() {
    remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );
}
```

Note that the [`admin_head-{$hook_suffix}`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L156) hook fires in the head section for a specific admin page. In the example above replacing `$hook_suffix` with `profile.php` in the hook name makes it run on the user admin profile page.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot. So, it's like I said in the comment to @josh-bonnick: Probably, it fires too early (before the `add_action`), but I'm a bit lost with finding out what/when/where to hook it...
So, I'm still having a hard time finding why [the recent move to admin-filters.php](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/commit/325d8bab0a6b949ed912e783d143cbf90c1e0a58) puts the `add_action` *after* my `remove_action`. Where do I see that in core's code?

Comment: A quick search in the WordPress source code shows that the  `default-filters.php` file is loaded on [line 134 in the wp-settings.php file](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L134), must-use plugins are loaded in that same file on [line 351](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L351). Without digging any further I can only assume that `admin-filters.php` is loaded later than your must-use plugin. When trying to figure out the load order, going down the rabbit hole and looking at the WordPress source code is your best bet.

Comment: I added on top the hook for `user-edit.php`: `add_action( 'admin_head-user-edit.php', 'wpse_72463738_remove_admin_color_scheme_picker' );`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the other part of the if statement in `user-edit.php` to remove the ability to change the color scheme.

From `user-edit.php`

```php
<?php if ( count( $_wp_admin_css_colors ) > 1 && has_action('admin_color_scheme_picker' ) ) : ?>
```

Although not a direct solution to using the remove action function, you can set the `$_wp_admin_css_colors` global to an empty array...

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
    global $_wp_admin_css_colors;
    $_wp_admin_css_colors = [];
} );
```

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I'd like to understand why the `remove_action` doesn't cut it anymore. In general, it seems to be the recommended way. Probably, it fires too early (before the `add_action`), but I'm a bit lost with finding out what/when/where to hook it.

Comment: @jovilog I tried hooking it into `admin_init` and `init` with a variety of priority values but it just wasn't having it - very stange.

Comment: Tried all that, too. I'm just not very adept in tracking such things down in code.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Barry Ceelen's answer if you want to remove `admin_color_scheme_picker` for both profile.php and user-edit.php screens you can do:

```
add_filter('admin_head',function($class){

        $screen = get_current_screen();
        
        if( in_array($screen->id,array(
        
            'profile',
            'user-edit',
        
        ))){

            // remove color picker
            
            remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker');
        }
});
```